# Ractive.js Calling object method from proxy event

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I would like to call a method of the specific object from ractive.

```
on-click="mylist.page(5)"
```

In this case mylist object with the next method would be set on the ractive object.

It works when I use next method added directly on the ractive object, but not when nested deeper inside

Comment: This would be a property on the Ractive instance, not an object from the data, right? `new Ractive( { el: '#el', template: '#template', mylist: { page: p => {...} } })`

Comment: yes. Just not sure what you mean by ':p' inside 'mylist:page:p=>'. What I have tried and didn't work was 'mylist:{page: function(){}}' but function 'page' is never called. removing 'mylist' both from the template and from the Ractive object would make it work.

Comment: See [this comment thread](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1684#issuecomment-97914124) for proposal for adding chained calls.

Comment: just a little ES6 :)  `p => {...}` same as `function(p) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ractive currently only supports calling one instance method in event handlers:

```
on-click='setPage(5)'
```

Being able to chain calls is [under consideration](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1684#issuecomment-97914124).

For now, you'd have to route it through a method:

```
new Ractive(){
    mylist: {
        page: function(page){
            // do page work
        }
    },
    setPage: function(page) {
        this.mylist.page(page);
    }
}
```

If what you really want is to call a method on a data object, add a prototype method to Ractive:

```
Ractive.prototype.call = function( obj, method ) {
    var args = [].prototype.slice.call( arguments, 2 );
    obj[method].apply( obj, args );
}
```

Then you can use:

```
on-click='call( mylist, "page", 5)'
```

Comment: Good to know! I did something similar as well (next:function(objet, pageNumber){}) but it didn't feel like a right way to do it. Especially when the application grows I wouldn't want to flatten out all the methods but instead group them into the objects.